# Динамический CSS

Tags: css

Возможно ли в CSS реализовать что то подобное?
В css

```
.margin_($n) {margin: ($n)px;}
```

а в html так:

```
<div class='margin_20'>отступили 20 px</div>
```

P.S. Только сильно не пинайте, просто мне совесть запретила писать в html style.
P.S.S. Ну вот отпинайте меня http://jsfiddle.net/hy2dg0uu/

Comment: почти так можно с помощью препроцессоров, но список значений n должен быть фиксированным

Comment: @Grundy а можно на примере?

Comment: например в scss есть [циклы](http://thesassway.com/intermediate/if-for-each-while#for) и стили можно просто сгенерировать

Comment: @Grundy ну сгенерировать я и на PHP могу. К сожалению не то что я хотел. Или я что то не так понял?

Comment: Такого в css нет. Либо генерировать стили, либо на js искать ваши классы и динамически устанавливать margin.

Comment: @wwwplaton, не могу придумать кейсов, где бы требовалось динамически навешивать маргин, и при этом чтобы это нельзя было решить с помощью заранее приготовленных стилей. Единственное, что я могу представить - это создание рекурсивных вложенностей (например, дерево файлов или древовидная система комментирования), но это также можно решить одним единственным заранее приготовленным классом. Пересматривайте структуру приложения, потому что в подавляющем большинстве случаев можно обойтись без изобретения велосипеда.

Comment: @terron походу ваш комментарий меня натолкнул на мысль одну. Нужно попробовать, может действительно одним обойдусь.

Comment: @terron если представить что это комментарии то у меня получается сделать только один отступ. Если в дереве передается отступ 10, 20 ... 50px то вот как это организовать ума не приложу :(

Comment: @wwwplaton, делайте по аналогии с вложенными друг в друга списками. Вот пример: https://jsfiddle.net/terron/z1jge6fg/2/

Comment: делайте ОДИН и тот же отступ, НО не от одного родителя, а от соседа, например от соседнего элемента сверху! и ничего высчитывать не надо! есть же ul + p { color: red; }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, конкретно в данном случае нет ни малейших плюсов от использования `class` вместо inline-стиля (экономия 2 символов не считается):

```
<div class='margin_20'>отступили 20 px</div>
<div style='margin:20px'>отступили 20 px</div>
```

Есть вариант, что нужна куча значений с префиксами, тогда класс действительно мог бы что-то дать. Но лучше ограничиться несколькими заранее определёнными значениями, а не пихать что попало. Например, сделать `margin-xs`, `margin-s`, ..., `margin-xxl`.

Что касается самого вопроса, теоретически [css позволяет вынесение части стилей в другие атрибуты](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/attr), но на данный момент **ни один браузер это не поддерживает:**

```css
p[data-ml] {
  margin-left: attr(data-ml px);
}
```

```html
<p data-ml="30">123</p>
<p data-ml="50">123</p>
<p data-ml="70">123</p>
```

Comment: экономии на самом деле нет, так как добавляется еще сам файл стилей

Comment: @Grundy, ну это смотря сколько раз повторить. Вдруг оно там 10000 раз встречается?)))

Comment: это да :-) не подумал об этом случае :)

Answer (score 0):

Совершенно непонятно зачем это нужно... Тем не менее, изменить уже подключенную к документу таблицу стилей можно, но не c помощью css. Из javascript можно получить таблицы стилей с помощью
var styleSheetList = document.styleSheets;
Скорее всего вы делаете что-то не то, если только вопрос не ради чистого интереса.

Answer (score -2):

С одним  `css` этого нельзя сделать, к сожалению :(

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?